# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from adding HTML tags to the plain text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my app, I'm using BeautifulSoup to process all the email templates before they are sent.

Some of them are complete HTML docs, but some of them are just plain texts (mostly used in tests).

As it's mentioned in the question title, I want to prevent BeautifulSoup from adding HTML tags around the plain text.

Here is the simplest example:

```py
soup1 = BeautifulSoup("Hello World!")
html1 = str(soup1)
print(html1)
```

current output:

```
'<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>'
```

expected output:

```
'Hello World!'
```

Comment: soup is for parsing and searching in HTML. I'm not sure I'm seeing where you would be going with this - I guess to not add the tags, you could not turn it into a soup - you would have the same text you started with (in this case, "Hello World!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into [BeautifulSoup docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#differences-between-parsers), I've found a solution.
All we have to do is specify "html.parser" when creating BeautifulSoup instance:

```py
soup1 = BeautifulSoup("Hello World!","html.parser")
html1 = str(soup1)
print(html1)
```

output:

```
'Hello World!'
```